# Drop Down Menu in Magento

Tags: magento

I have this code in template to make a static home button. On the home button on hover over I would like to have a blog button underneath.

```php
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
  <?php if($_menu): ?>
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="container_24">
      <div class="grid_24">
        <div id="menu-icon">Categories</div>
        <ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
          <li class="level0 level-top<?php if (Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() === Mage::helper('core/url')->getHomeUrl()) echo ' active'; ?>">
            <a class="level-top" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('')?>">
              <span>Home</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <?php echo $_menu ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Can you try specifying the problem you have and the help you are hoping for?

Comment: Hi Well i have a have a static menu button on lhs of my menu, that is my home button. I would like to have a Blog button underneath it so on hover over the blog button appears